# Generics: Same-type constraint type 'G' does not conform to required protocol 'Generator'

Tags: swift

I'm working on a Generator class that wraps another Generator and provides some extra features on top of it. I've got pretty much everything working except for one thing: a convenience init that takes a Sequence as a parameter and automatically creates a generator from it.

This is the code that is causing the error:

```
class MyGenerator<G: Generator>: Generator {
    typealias Element = G.Element

    var generator: G

    init (_ generator: G) {
        self.generator = generator
    }

    // ERROR: Same-type constraint type 'G' does not conform to 
    // required protocol 'Generator'
    convenience init<S: Sequence where S.GeneratorType == G>(sequence: S) {
        self.init(sequence.generate())
    }

    // [...]

    func next() -> Element? {
        return generator.next()
    }
}
```

What's going on here? Why Swift doesn't like my constraint? It looks ok to me.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a compiler bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a compiler bug, you can work it around by changing generic argument from generator to element and using `GeneratorOf<T>` for an extra level of indirection:

```
class MyGenerator<T>: Generator {
    typealias Element = T

    var generator: GeneratorOf<T>

    init<G: Generator where G.Element == T>(_ generator: G) {
        self.generator = GeneratorOf(generator)
    }

    convenience init<S: Sequence where S.GeneratorType.Element == T>(sequence: S) {
        self.init(sequence.generate())
    }

    // [...]

    func next() -> Element? {
        return generator.next()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually arrived at the same conclusion myself, but I was waiting to post it to see if anyone knew how to avoid the GeneratorOf<T>.